# Diamond Shape Output With `for` Loops

Tags: c, loops

The program is simply to create the shape of a diamond when the user input the number of rows so simply it has 6 for loops; 3 loops to create the first triangle and 3 loops to create the other triangle, and with these 2 triangles and 6 loops we have a diamond,this is an image of the whole program:

[image]

I'm a little confused about the 5th for loop, the one that creates the spaces for the second triangle, the loop begins by adding 1st space then the loop ends, the program continues to the 6th loop and get back to the 4th loop to do the 5th & 6th loops all over, the 5 loops is adding 1,2,3,.. spaces ever time and we can see that from: `spaces++`, the problem is how is this working? the counter c is also getting higher every time, `c++`, so the difference between(space and c) will still be 1 every time so it suppose to be adding only one space every time, for those who understood what I was saying can you explain this too me

```
int n, c, k, space = 1;

  printf("Enter number of rows\n");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  space = n - 1;

  for (k = 1; k <= n; k++)
  {
    for (c = 1; c <= space; c++)
      printf(" ");

    space--;

    for (c = 1; c <= 2*k-1; c++)
      printf("*");

    printf("\n");
  }

  space = 1;

  for (k = 1; k <= n - 1; k++)
  {
    for (c = 1; c <= space; c++)
      printf(" ");

   space++;

    for (c = 1 ; c <= 2*(n-k)-1; c++)
      printf("*");

    printf("\n");
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.   please read these links ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask
http://sscce.org/ ) on how to post a question.  You will get a better outcome that way.

http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Learn how to format and take some time on spelling. I'm tired of correcting people from spelling **im** and **u**. Sure most people understand it, but the fact that you don't take time to use correct spelling shows no respect to the people who's trying to help.

Comment: 6 `for` loops? Please make them nested!

Comment: @darksphere - He is not the only one. See the score next to the comment

Comment: Please add example output, even if it's not from running the code.

Comment: Why not create a rectangle first of the correct dimensions that can just hold the diamond? Then just add some logic to decide on if the character is a space or '*'?

Comment: counter c is also getting back to the value '1' when the 5th and 6th loop starts every time !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the counter c is also getting higher every time, c++, so the
>   difference between(space and c) will still be 1 every time

No, `space++` is not part of the loop that increments c. That loop prints `space` spaces; after it finishes, space is incremented, so the next time it will print 1 more space.

Answer (score 0):

After 5th for loop you should add space++;.Otherwise diamond won't be right shape.